# How do I use <c:set> in <c:forEach> loop of Bean objects?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl

I'm STUCK and could use really your help. I need to use a `JSTL c:set` tag or `JavaScript` to post user's input back to the server. I have a `servlet` called `StarTeamServer` which has an `ArrayList` of `UserAccessDetailObject` beans. The `JSP` displays the `ArrayList` table results fine, but I have no idea how to code the `c:set` on the `forEach` indexed `loop`. I hope you can please provide some examples to help..

```
 //Servlet where I load ArrayList and add it into session scope
 public class StarTeamServer{
    private ArrayList<UserAccessDetailObject> requestedUsersSecurityAccessDetailObjectList = new ArrayList<UserAccessDetailObject>();

    public ArrayList<UserAccessDetailObject> getRequestedUsersSecurityAccessDetailObjectList() {
      ect...
    }

    public void setRequestedUsersSecurityAccessDetailObjectList(
      ect...
    }
   ect...

   session.setAttribute("STServerBean", stServer);
  } 

 //A bean object that is stored in Array
 public class UserAccessDetailObject {

   private String serverName = "";
   private String serverPort = "";
   private String serverProjectName = ""; 

   public String getServerName() {
    return serverName;
   }
   public void setServerName(String serverName) {
    this.serverName = serverName;
   }
   ect ..........
 }  

 //JSP using JSTL forEach loop is working to display data from the server in the JSP.
 <Form method="post" name="formToSubmit"  id="formToSubmit" action="ControllerSubmitRequest" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <jsp:useBean id="STServerBean" type="com.bis.alm.model.StarTeamServer" class="com.bis.alm.model.StarTeamServer"    scope="session" />
  <c:forEach var="userAccessDetailObject" items="${STServerBean.requestedUsersSecurityAccessDetailObjectList}" varStatus="theCount">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="serverNameID_${theCount.count}" value="${userAccessDetailObject.serverName}" /></td>                                         
      <td><input type="text" name="serverPortID_${theCount.count}" value="${userAccessDetailObject.serverPort}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${theCount.count}"></c:out></td>                        
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: you should set this object in `page-context` or `request`  Object of Servlet and sent it to the servlet.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the code syntax to use for c:set in a forEach?? I need to pass back the user's input into the server. I have the scope set to session which I believe should exist beyond the request or page.